# How to minimize a function involving NIntegrate?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, numerics, mathematical-optimization

I have three datasets as follow:

```
d1 = {7.813540819717949`, 6.529568930239602`, 8.109143155429088`, 7.689731068450451`, 8.74120436001789`, 7.4987912906550225`, 7.615218703959835`, 8.247993113806512`, 7.2855561696238285`, 7.166026422873959`, 7.378283448111686`, 7.3970482801481445`, 7.021646802522941`, 7.1487021619286235`, 7.209809605280611`, 7.872181282365198`, 7.984087026932971`, 7.264607460785361`, 7.491235907642249`, 6.986130172036584`, 8.132032453432691`, 6.738507551311768`, 7.634485996132314`, 7.786727105539017`, 6.747498220290592`, 5.652606213674484`, 6.7145418893159245`, 7.3870764772231245`, 8.14556152457044`, 7.081683553610293`, 7.878354128765276`, 7.502128544096253`, 7.445033772765536`, 8.112365581746175`, 6.964895579434653`, 7.98895773278444`, 7.097718201996728`, 6.6447632395708816`, 7.014871229850273`, 7.596255451339725`, 7.327487147907844`, 7.626051696868463`, 7.973711939912565`, 7.497221611664195`, 7.6858101713490985`, 8.629983423881175`, 6.599398955562014`, 6.833800440038957`, 7.171926480447397`, 5.789311864786593`, 7.089675372368081`, 6.1631268127766665`, 7.639965587796188`, 7.086047166284019`, 5.406270852788866`, 6.93340616203404`, 5.807420811406816`, 6.419517442993749`, 7.414925539201528`, 7.33535213385308`, 8.263651842593319`, 6.164116766463783`, 6.947143869593553`, 6.9901653234057335`};

d2 = {3.5113704043630944`, 7.608006873863145`, 7.277906729276423`, 8.103217766965727`, 7.250931121957523`, 7.8289541079690075`, 6.974346234874238`, 8.270349382459646`, 8.10910442305307`, 6.9048101280375365`, 7.325825456049268`, 7.73757379706066`, 6.765535372291408`, 6.785935805992911`, 6.688548887697433`, 8.459691239773468`, 8.186443329842977`, 6.460124310707724`, 5.331370159943533`, 7.509021973926822`, 5.895785915422184`, 7.155632848713018`, 6.297014977893012`, 7.024257130369493`, 6.7061658261632875`, 6.076510324090876`, 6.619713727473183`, 6.806885656438763`, 6.29566021880475`, 6.379851689698886`, 5.886155198942714`, 6.711177147084791`, 6.0644975554789955`, 6.476320208302014`, 5.555972713843852`, 5.445658305743026`, 4.106563198219526`, 9.662304286781078`, 7.245526688643017`, 7.729224257804472`, 7.348730647320301`, 6.811708787441987`, 6.453437984409927`, 6.251602287446226`, 6.222552426881395`, 6.325257487433763`, 6.561448036981885`, 6.992186187552647`, 6.581755244192236`, 6.35555449505844`, 6.356911340563265`, 5.993472986445495`, 6.8937984018722185`, 6.475209760379862`, 5.709341745086517`, 5.993789526904261`, 5.81235159806516`, 5.929503391669893`, 6.692420198312638`, 6.897925343017829`, 7.935826808183915`, 5.21638101511404`, 6.0629537994613605`, 5.011619213604298`, 5.329736171185173`, 5.581381723984043`, 5.386724423467079`, 6.8984666598061235`, 6.624173458096634`, 5.9758576034447595`, 6.262093086610586`, 6.191574403265945`, 6.345257463708366`, 6.691754218111958`};

d3 = {11.3197, 10.9668, 10.6479, 11.6099, 10.2554, 11.3928, 11.1466, 8.62521, 9.39976, 8.52043, 9.68226, 9.16244, 9.56907, 9.6331, 10.0117, 11.9325, 11.0703, 10.2413, 10.1749, 11.377, 9.48853, 9.27371, 8.69103, 9.91404, 10.1807, 8.29698, 9.88819, 9.10128, 11.2514, 8.5246, 9.90356, 9.61888, 9.94975, 10.562, 10.3259, 10.5507, 10.3181, 10.4145, 10.6412, 9.67268, 10.5768};
```

Now, I need to calculate the entropy of each of the above data from their corresponding histograms; however, the bin widths of histograms are not known. I should determine the bin widths in such a way that the function $g$, defined below, to be minimized.

Thus, first, we write for the entropies as:

```
e1[y_] := NIntegrate[With[{f = PDF[HistogramDistribution[d1, {y}], x]}, If[f > 0, -f Log[f], 0]], {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]

e2[z_] := NIntegrate[With[{f = PDF[HistogramDistribution[d2, {z}], x]}, If[f > 0, -f Log[f], 0]], {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]

e3[w_] := NIntegrate[With[{f = PDF[HistogramDistribution[d3, {w}], x]}, If[f > 0, -f Log[f], 0]], {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]
```

where $y$, $z$, and $w$ are the bin widths of histograms, and the entropy is defined as usual.

The bin widths should be chosen in such a way that the following function to be minimized:

```
g[x_, y_, z_, w_] := (0.40) Log[(0.40)/((E^(-x (e1[y])))/(E^(-x (e1[y])) + E^(-x (e2[z])) + E^(-x (e3[w]))))]
+ (0.38) Log[(0.38)/((E^(-x (e2[z])))/(E^(-x (e1[y])) + E^(-x (e2[z])) + E^(-x (e3[w]))))]
+ (0.22) Log[(0.22)/((E^(-x (e3[w])))/(E^(-x (e1[y])) + E^(-x (e2[z])) + E^(-x (e3[w]))))]
```

so:

```
FindMinimum[{g[x, y, z, w], x > 0 && y > 0 && z > 0 && w > 0}, {x, y, z, w}]
```

At this stage, *Mathematica* returns errors. I think, NIntegrate cannot be defined in terms of variables. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Try [`?NumericQ`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26037/193) on the arguments.

Comment: Yes, that certainly eliminates the errors.  The code, however, is quite slow.

Comment: Use `f[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ, w_?NumericQ]` and similarly for other arguments.

Comment: `Plot[e1[y], {y, .01, 50}, MaxRecursion -> 5, PlotPoints -> 50,  PlotRange -> All]` produces noisy results for `y < 10`.  Is this reasonable?

Comment: `Plot[e1[y], {y, .01, 1}, MaxRecursion -> 3, PlotPoints -> 10,  PlotRange -> All]` is noisy throughout.  `FindMinimum` will not work well as a result.  Try the plot.

Comment: I do not know.  Try plotting `e1` to see.

Comment: I do not know how to do that.  Perhaps, you can fit your data to a smooth curve.  By the way, note that I first checked the components of your code before trying to understand why the code as a whole was not working well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a different approach that may raise some issues with the Question itself.  As I noted in comments above, the functions listed in the question are quite noisy, and `FindMinimum` does not converge in any reasonable amount of time.  Consequently, as suggested by the OP in a comment above, JimB in his answer used an alternative function,

```
e[y_?NumericQ, d_] := 
    Module[{skd, dmin, dmax, g}, skd = SmoothKernelDistribution[d, y];
    {dmin, dmax} = MinMax[d] + 3.9 y {-1, 1};
    g = PDF[skd, a][[1, 1, 1]];
    NIntegrate[-g Log[g], {a, dmin, dmax}]]
```

Plotting this function for the three data sets in the question yields

```
Plot[e[y, d1], {y, .04, 1}, MaxRecursion -> 3, PlotPoints -> 10, 
    PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {y, "e1"}, ImageSize -> Large, 
    LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[e[y, d2], {y, .12, 1}, MaxRecursion -> 3, PlotPoints -> 10, 
    PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {y, "e2"}, ImageSize -> Large, 
    LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[e[y, d3], {y, .04, 1}, MaxRecursion -> 3, PlotPoints -> 10, 
    PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {y, "e3"}, ImageSize -> Large, 
    LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

Note that these plots cannot be extended to smaller values of `y`, because `e` becomes complex there.  Note, also, that these plots are somewhat different from those obtained from `{e1, e2, e3}` in the question.  They are, however, smooth.

Turn now to the quantity to be minimized.  As JimB points out, it can be simplified somewhat.

```
Expand[FunctionExpand[(0.40) Log[(0.40)/((E^(-x (e1[
           y])))/(E^(-x (e1[y])) + E^(-x (e2[z])) + 
       E^(-x (e3[w]))))] + (0.38) Log[(0.38)/((E^(-x (e2[
           z])))/(E^(-x (e1[y])) + E^(-x (e2[z])) + 
       E^(-x (e3[w]))))] + (0.22) Log[(0.22)/((E^(-x (e3[
           w])))/(E^(-x (e1[y])) + E^(-x (e2[z])) + 
       E^(-x (e3[w]))))]] /. Log[z1_ z2_] -> Log[z1] + Log[z2]]
(* -1.06731 + 0.4 Log[E^(x e1[y])] + 0.38 Log[E^(x e2[z])] + 0.22 Log[E^(x e3[w])]
    + 1. Log[E^(-x e1[y]) + E^(-x e2[z]) + E^(-x e3[w])] *)
```

Suppose, now, we make the substitution,

```
% /. {x e1[y] -> h1, x e2[z] -> h2, x e3[w] -> h3}
(* -1.06731 + 0.4 Log[E^h1] + 0.38 Log[E^h2] + 0.22 Log[E^h3] + 
   1. Log[E^-h1 + E^-h2 + E^-h3] *)
```

So, there are only three quantities to be varied in the minimization process.  This explains in part the multiple solutions obtained by JimB.  However, to perform the minimization, lower bounds must be put on `{h1, h2, h3}`.  If we assume, arbitrarily, that `x = 1`, then we have from the plots above,

```
s = NMinimize[{%, h1 > .8, h2 > 1.3, h3 > 1}, {h1, h2, h3}]
(* {3.63403*10^-7, {h1 -> 1.2487, h2 -> 1.3, h3 -> 1.84653}} *)
```

obtained in a few seconds.  Next, find

```
FindRoot[e[y, d1] - h1 /. s[[2]], {y, .4}]
(* {y -> 0.506467} *)
FindRoot[e[y, d2] - h2 /. s[[2]], {y, .127, .2}]
(* {y -> 0.161228} *)
FindRoot[e[y, d3] - h3 /. s[[2]], {y, 1.2}]
(* {y -> 1.24325} *)
```

Different choices for `x` yields different results for the arguments of `e`.  On this basis, it would appear that the solution space `{x, y, z, w}` is not a point but a one-dimensional space.  In fact, it is a two-dimensional space, as can be seen from

```
ListLinePlot3D[Table[Join[{n}, 
    ArgMin[{f /. h1 -> n, h2 > 0, h3 > 0}, {h2, h3}]], {n, 0, 1, .01}],
    BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {1/2, 3/2}}, 
    AxesLabel -> {h1, h2, h3}, ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

and `f = 0` to within `10^-6` along the curve.

**Addendum - Symbolic Minimization of f**

Interestingly, rationalizing `f` and modifying the definitions of `h2` and `h3` (i.e., `{x e2[z] -> h1 + h2, x e3[w] -> h1 + h3}`) eliminates `h1`.

```
Expand[FunctionExpand[
    (40/100) Log[(40/100)/((E^(-x (e1[y])))/(E^(-x (e1[y])) + E^(-x (e2[z])) + 
       E^(-x (e3[w]))))] + 
    (38/100) Log[(38/100)/((E^(-x (e2[z])))/(E^(-x (e1[y])) + E^(-x (e2[z])) + 
       E^(-x (e3[w]))))] + 
    (22/100) Log[(22/100)/((E^(-x (e3[w])))/(E^(-x (e1[y])) + E^(-x (e2[z])) + 
       E^(-x (e3[w]))))]] /. Log[z1_ z2_] -> Log[z1] + Log[z2]];
% /. {x e1[y] -> h1, x e2[z] -> h1 + h2, x e3[w] -> h1 + h3};
f = Simplify[% /. Log[Exp[z1_ + z2_]] -> Log[Exp[z1]] + Log[Exp[z2]] /. 
    Log[z1_ + z2_ + z3_] -> Log[z1] + Log[1 + z2/z1 + z3/z1], h1 >= 0]
(* 1/50 (-20 Log[5/2] - 19 Log[50/19] - 11 Log[50/11] + 19 Log[E^h2] + 
   11 Log[E^h3] + 50 Log[1 + E^-h2 + E^-h3]) *)
```

which minimizes to an exact solution.

```
FullSimplify[Minimize[{f, h2 > 0, h3 > 0}, {h2, h3}]]
(* {0, {h2 -> Log[20/19], h3 -> Log[20/11]}} *)
```

That `h1` does not enter into this result reinforces the observation above that the original problem has a two-dimensional space of solutions. Specific values for `{y, z, w}` now are obtained numerically from

```
x e1[y] == h1
x e2[z] == h1 + Log[20/19]
x e3[w] == h1 + Log[20/11]
```

with positive `x` and `h1` chosen at will.

Comment: @Samane  The computation is fast, because minimization is performed before evaluating the coordinates `{y, z, w}`.  I suggest you consider two issues.  First, what is the best way to represent your data, and second, how can you best utilize the range of solutions.

Comment: @Samane This is exactly why one wants to wait a bit before accepting an answer.  (I think if I edit my question that allows you to unaccept my "answer".)

Comment: @Samane  You may find the symbolic minimization that I just added to be of interest.  Thanks for accepting my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider a single function for calculating the entropy values:

```
e[y_?NumericQ, d_] := Module[{skd, dmin, dmax, g},
  skd = SmoothKernelDistribution[d, y];
  {dmin, dmax} = MinMax[d] + 3.9 y {-1, 1};
  g = PDF[skd, a][[1, 1, 1]];
  NIntegrate[-g Log[g], {a, dmin, dmax}]]
```

Rather than integrating from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, I've used 3.9 times the bandwidth above and below the maximum and minimum values in the dataset.  A multiplier larger than 4 will result in a zero value for the pdf and cause issues.

Also the function to be minimized can probably be simplified.  If I did the simplification correctly, I get the following:

```
f[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ, w_?NumericQ] :=
 -1.0673063239076608 + 0.4 e[y, d1] x + 0.38 e[z, d2] x + 
  0.22 e[w, d3] x + Log[E^(-e[y, d1] x) + E^(-e[z, d2] x) + E^(-e[w, d3] x)]
```

Minimizing the function took about 21 minutes on my 5-year-old PC:

```
AbsoluteTiming[sol = FindMinimum[{f[x, y, z, w], x > 0 && y > 0 && z > 0 && w > 0}, {x, y, z, w}]]
(* {1265.76, {1.24345*10^-14, {x -> 3.92559, y -> 1.66405, z -> 1.54815, w -> 1.89182}}} *)
```

I don't know if a value of 1.24345*10^-14 for $f$ makes any sense or not.  Different starting values (which are all 1 in this case) might result in a different set of estimated parameters.

**Addition 1**

Why integrate from `Min[d1] - 3.9 y` to `Max[d1] + 3.9 y` rather than $-\infty$ to $\infty$ or `Min[d1]` to `Max[d1]`?

`SmoothKernelDistribution` (with a Gaussian kernel) produces a pdf that has positive values from `Min[d1] - 5 y` to `Min[d1] - 5 y` and zero elsewhere:

```
y = 1.66405;
PDF[SmoothKernelDistribution[d1, y], x]
```

[image: PDF for dataset d1]

```
Min[d1] - 5*y <= x <= Max[d1] + 5*y
(* -4.59373 <= x <= 18.7412 *)
```

But suppose one integrated the PDF from `Min[d1]` to `Max[d1]` compared to `Min[d1] - 3.9 y`, `Max[d1] + 3.9 y`:

```
y = 1.66405;
NIntegrate[PDF[SmoothKernelDistribution[d1, y], x], {x, Min[d1], Max[d1]}]
(* 0.642989 *)
NIntegrate[PDF[SmoothKernelDistribution[d1, y], x], {x, Min[d1] - 3.9 y, 
  Max[d1] + 3.9 y}]
(* 0.999994 *)
```

Using just the min and max did not capture enough of the probability.

So why use 3.9 rather than 5 as the multiplier?  For your transformation of the entropy I got underflow errors when using 5 and even when using 4.  Using 3.9 seemed to capture most of the probability (i.e., integrating close to 1) and didn't produce errors.

**Additional 2**

Stability of the results.

Using different starting values very close to the previous results resulted in an even smaller minimum for $f$ and very different parameter values:

```
AbsoluteTiming[sol = FindMinimum[{f[x, y, z, w], 
    x > 0 && y > 0 && z > 0 && w > 0}, {{x, 4}, {y, 1.7}, {z, 1.5}, {w, 1.9}}]]

{888.965, {0., {x -> 4.5959, y -> 2.25562, z -> 2.18019, w -> 2.52917}}}
```

There appears to be some numeric stability issues.  You probably need to `Rationalize` the constants (i.e., 0.4 -> 4/10, 0.38 -> 38/100, 0.22 -> 22/100, etc.) and raise the `WorkingPrecision` in `FindMinimum`.

Comment: Sorry, yes, it's the minimum of $f$.  I'll fix that.  I'll also add an explanation as to why using min - 3.9 y and max + 3.9 y is just a little bit better than just the min and max.

Comment: I do not believe that your analysis is unstable.  Instead, there is a two-dimension space of solutions, as can be seen by my analysis below.